# Use command in pyenv instead of command in homebrew

Tags: linux, bash, pip, sshuttle

### Problem

I bought a MacBook Pro and I transfered all data from MacBook Air. And when I installed `sshuttle` by using command `pip install sshuttle` and I tried to execute `sshuttle -r host 0/0`, the following error occured.

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/sshuttle: No such file or directory
```

So I found out I need to fix sshuttle's path to pyenv one. 
How to change the path of command to pyenv's one.

That is what I want to change

```
$ which sshuttle
/Users/Me/.pyenv/shims/sshuttle
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add `/Users/Me/.pyenv/shims` to your PATH variable by adding `export PATH="/Users/Me/.pyenv/shims/:$PATH"` to your .bash_profile. Another option, if you just want this particular executable as opposed to everything in the directory, would be to put `alias sshuttle= "/Users/Me/.pyenv/shims/sshuttle"` in your .bash_profile.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I solved with your idea.